# How to develop a IPad Application using Java in Windows

Tags: ipad, jsp

How to develop a IPad Application using Java in Windows, am a Java developer with Eclipse IDE on Windows OS,
i would like to know is there any way to develop a application for Ipad with my above mentioned resources....?

thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone just said when they were posting the link to this question, you are being quite optimistic with these requirements.

Quite simply, it isn't going to happen, not unless you stick to jail broken devices and some kind soul has ported a JVM to IOS, which I haven't heard of.

You have no way of deploying to a non-jailbroken device, as Apple only provide provisioning certificates to XCode, and Xcode handles deployment.

You have no way of running Java without either a JVM (not going to happen on a non-jailbroken device) or a conversion tool like MonoTouch for .Net, again I haven't heard of one.

In short, no chance.

Comment: well... this means even if some how we develop a Ipad App in windows OS it will stick only on JailBroken devices.. and if we want our app to run on IPad it need to be developed on IOS with Xcode ... Correct...?

Comment: Even with a jail broken device, you still need to either convert to IOS native code, or you need a JVM available, neither of which is currently possible as far as I am aware.  Just stick to XCode on a Mac, your life will be infinitely easier - you will never get your approach to work.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need Xcode on a Mac. This is unlikely to change.
Also requires Objective C knowledge or something that uses it (like Phonegap)

Xcode is like Eclipse (but so so much better and prettier), Objective-C is like Java, a powerful OO c-style language that you do everything in.

Comment: ok... Xcode, is it entirely different from JAVA or similar to java programming, like syntax, coding methods... etc

Comment: XCode is a development environment, like Visual Studio or Eclipse.  IOS apps are developed in C, C++ or Objective-C, which are languages like Java, but all have different syntax and coding methods to Java.

Comment: @Warrior Learning Java will help you learn ObjC a lot.

Comment: thanks.. i guess Object-C stands on OOPS ...?